# How to get data from firebase and then push it back

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stuck with getting data from firebase and then push it back after some changes.

The code given below work with issues, because I need to get int and push sum of its and another value to the Realtime Database once, but it push it multiple times, after last time it was more than 39K rows, except 1.

```
private DatabaseReference ratingReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Consts.RATING_DB);

 public void setRating(String uid, int addPoint) {
        ratingReference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int rating = 0;
                if (dataSnapshot.child(Consts.RATING).getValue() != null) {
                    rating = Integer.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(Consts.RATING).getValue().toString());
                }
                DatabaseReference ref =  ratingReference.child(getUid()).push();
                Map<String, Object> ratingMap = new HashMap<>();
                ratingMap.put("rating", rating + addPoint);
                ref.updateChildren(ratingMap);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
```

I`ll be really grateful, if you help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Consts.RATING` holds a String value similar with `rating` and the type of this property is a **number** and **not** a String, to add the value of `addPoint` to the existing `rating` value, please use the following lines of code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long rating = 0;

        if(dataSnapshot.child(Consts.RATING).exists()) {
            rating = dataSnapshot.child(Consts.RATING).getValue(Long.class);
            long newValue = rating + addPoint;
            dataSnapshot.child(Consts.RATING).getRef().setValue(newValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
ratingReference.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you can see, there is no need to use any `push()` call.

Comment: @AndréKool No, it won't. Please take a look at my code. I have already used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Hi! Yes, it is working! Thank you for your help!  And sorry for my long absence.